# Oracle Stored Procedure and PyODBC

Tags: python, oracle, pyodbc

I am having some trouble with getting PyODBC to work with a proc in Oracle.

Below is the code and the output

db = pyodbc.connect('DSN=TEST;UID=cantsay;PWD=cantsay')

```
print('-' * 20)
try:
    c = db.cursor()
    rs = c.execute("select * from v$version where banner like 'Oracle%'")
    for txt in c.fetchall():
        print('%s' % (txt[0]))
    test = ""
    row = c.execute("call DKB_test.TESTPROC('7894','789465','789465')").fetchall()
finally:
    db.close()
```

OUTPUT

```
>    C:\Documents and Settings\dex\Desktop>orctest.py
> -------------------- Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Documents and
> Settings\dex\Desktop\orctest.py", line 31, in <module>
>     row = c.execute("{call DKB_test.TESTPROC(12354,78946,123 4)}").fetchall()
> pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-06550: line 1,
> column 7: \nPLS-00221: 'TESTPROC' is not a procedure
> or is undefined\nORA- 06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement
> ignored\n (6550) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

But I can see this procedure and coding it in c# it works, but this project I am doing is requiring python for now.

I did some Google searches and nothing comes up that helps me.

Any thing will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, The procedure name is Get_SC_From_Comp_Ven_Job or GET_SC_FROM_COMP_VEN_JOB?

1. check the userspace is correct or not.
2. check the name case-sensitive, if we create procedure Get_SC_From_Comp_Ven_Job, actually it is GET_SC_FROM_COMP_VEN_JOB. but if we create procedure "Get_SC_From_Comp_Ven_Job", then it is

Comment: Well I made the cap changes and now I get a new error.                         pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
\nPLS-00221: 'TEST' is not a procedure or is undefined\nORA-
06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored\n (6550) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: @thedemon, at least there is progress:-). what is TEST? not able to find it in your code.

Comment: sorry this is just a generic for the procedure. Any ideas on what else I am doing wrong?

Comment: I mean the message: PLS-00221: 'TEST' is not a procedure or is undefined, there must be somewhere reference TEST in the procedure, but in the code you posted, can not find TEST referenced anywhere.